# Getting "not all code paths return a value" when using ExceptionDispatchInfo.Capture

Tags: c#, reflection

I'm working on a method which uses reflection to call another method. That "other method" can, however, throw an exception and I'd like to propagate that exception with it's original stack information and `InnerException`. That is simply because the method that uses reflection is not supposed to handle the exception, the caller should.

Here's a simplified version of the code:

```
public static bool Test() {
    try {
        return (bool) typeof(Program).GetMethod("OtherMethod").Invoke(null, null);
    } catch(TargetInvocationException ex) {
        ExceptionDispatchInfo.Capture(ex.InnerException).Throw();
    }
}

public static bool OtherMethod() {
    throw new InvalidOperationException();
}
```

That code obviously won't compile, since the `Test` method (according to the compiler) doesn't always return a value.
I could add a `return false` after the `ExceptionDispatchInfo.Capture` but I was wondering if there's a nicer way of achieving the same thing. Without writing the redundant `return false`.

I know it's kind of a nitpick question, but I can't help wondering. Plus, redundant code gives me an itch :P

Comment: You don't have much choice here. The compiler cannot infer that `Throw()` will actually throw, so from its point of view there are code paths that don't return a value indeed. Adding a `return` statement looks like the only solution.

Comment: How simplified is this? Because this code could just `throw ex.InnerException;` . The simplification seems to be hurting the question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is one other option: instead of adding a redundant `return false;` you could add a redundant `throw;`.
You then don't need to make up a return value. (OK, not a big deal for a `bool`)

Answer (score 1):

The simplest solution that doesn't give you redundant or duplicated code is to only put things inside your `try` that are actually going to throw. Creating your `bool`, assigning it `false` and returning it are all "safe" operations, so leave them outside the `try`.

```
public static bool Test()
{
    bool returnValueOfInvoke = false;
    try
    {
        returnValueOfInvoke = (bool)typeof(Program).GetMethod("OtherMethod").Invoke(null, null);    
    }
    catch(TargetInvocationException ex)
    {
        ExceptionDispatchInfo.Capture(ex.InnerException).Throw();
    }
    return returnValueOfInvoke;
}

public static void OtherMethod()
{
    throw new InvalidOperationException();
}
```

Comment: Please view the revised question, the Invoke() is supposed to return a bool. Forgot to add that aspect.

Comment: Basically the same deal; instantiate a variable that will go into the `try`, pick up the value, and come out with it for you to return. If you really want, you can make it nullable and check for null values after the `try`, throwing something suitable if it's still null.